# Tsrange calculation of time intervals?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

I have a table with room reserve:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (room int, during tsrange);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES
    (1108, '[2010-01-01 09:30, 2010-01-01 10:30)');
```

**Question:**

I need to get the remaining free intervals for this room: 30 min, 45min, 1 hour and 1.30 minutes during the day (09.00 - 18.00).
How to do it?
Thanks to all.

Comment: I see two free intervals 0:30 and 7:30... how you get yours?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will return all free intervals for all days for which there are entries in `reservation`:

```
WITH mins(lt) AS (
   /* get all lower bounds of intervals */
   SELECT lower(during)
   FROM reservation
   UNION
   /* get 18:00 for each day */
   SELECT date_trunc('day', lower(during)) + INTERVAL '18 hours'
   FROM reservation
), maxs(ut) AS (
   /* get all upper bounds of intervals */
   SELECT upper(during)
   FROM reservation
   UNION
   /* get 09:00 for each day */
   SELECT date_trunc('day', lower(during)) + INTERVAL '9 hours'
   FROM reservation
)
SELECT tsrange(ut, lt)  /* candidate for a free interval */
FROM mins
   JOIN maxs
      ON date_trunc('day', lt) = date_trunc('day', ut)
         AND ut < lt
/* exclude all such intervals that overlap an entry */
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reservation
                  WHERE during && tsrange(ut, lt, '()'))
ORDER BY ut;
```

Filtering them by length is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what is needed!

Comment: You can ask a new question for that.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much